# About light nature

Tags: visible-light, telescopes, dispersion

I have some particular questions about the nature of light...cause all I know from all sources is that it is a wave and a particle and stuffs, but if light "COMES" from all directions, and is in every point, light from all angles passing through, how is it that it is not "distorted" some how, what I mean is, if for example a light beam coming from a single point of a galaxy, of a single wavelength, crashes with another wave coming from a different direction and angle, with a different wavelength, how is that they just pass one another and continue as if nothing has happen?. 
And the other question is, how much can light be dispersed?, I mean, it is supposed that the space fabric is continuum, if a telescope works by doing this, magnifying light, what stops scientist to exploit this and really look at the most tiny thing from cosmological distances? like a single dot, expand it, and then every single dot of the expansion, expand it again, and so on.

Comment: How does one expand a pixel (dot)?

Answer (score 0):

Your first question can be explained by the classical laws of electromagnetism. Classically, electric fields can be in a superposition where they either add or subtract. This means that waves which criss cross do in fact interact in the sense that they add up to a point of constructive or destructive interference in that region.

For your second question about observing distant objects there are a few practical limitations. For one thing, as you get further away from an object emitting light, eventually you will only receive one photon of light at a time. That is one discrete particle. Because we only receive a few particles of light at a time from distant objects, we tend to observe them or expose our cameras to them for a long time in order to collect a lot of light resulting in more information and a more meaningful observation.

Answer (score 0):

> if for example a light beam coming from a single point of a galaxy, of a single wavelength, crashes with another wave coming from a different direction and angle, with a different wavelength, how is that they just pass one another and continue as if nothing has happen?

In classical electrodynamics, where we treat light as electromagnetic waves that simply propagate through space, it is true that the light beams will simply pass through each other. This is because light acts not as a physical object, but more as a disturbance in a field that propagates outward at c. For an intuitive analogy, light can be considered to be similar to a ripple of water on a pond. If you create two different ripples, they don't crash or collide at the boundary, they merely pass through each other.

However, the more recent quantum theory of light states that light can be thought of as made up of tiny particles of light, each particle known as a photon, with a specific energy that is related to its frequency. At low energies, photons behave just as classical waves behave, in that they mainly ignore each other. However, at high energies of the order of 500 MeV, a pair of photons can annihilate creating an electron-positron pair with a substantial probability. This is a consequence of $E = mc^2$, where Energy and matter are intrinsically related, and under the right circumstances can be interchanged.

> it is supposed that the space fabric is continuum, if a telescope works by doing this, magnifying light, what stops scientist to exploit this and really look at the most tiny thing from cosmological distances?

Yes, this is pretty much what telescopes do, not really an 'exploit' but what they are made for. The trouble is, light from very far away is usually incredibly weak, due to several factors, (redshift from the expansion of the universe which increases the further away the light source is, how the intensity of light drops off as you get further and further away from the light source, etc). But in essence telescopes aim to collect this light.

Comment: *"quantum theory of light states that light can be thought of as made up of tiny particles of light, each particle known as a photon, with a specific energy that is related to its frequency. "* Assuming this was true, say I had a tiny particle of the kind you mean with frequency 1THz. What do you think the size of such particle would be?

Comment: @JánLalinský Well a photon really is just a wavepacket, like a wave localised in space or something that propogates along right? It would really depend on your definition of 'size', but doesn't size have no meaning when dealing with QM, because of wave-particle duality? When we observe a photon as a particle though, shouldn't it have a definite position as a point particle? Does size even mean anything?

Comment: In the answer you said quantum theory of light states photons are tiny particles. Now you're saying size does not have meaning. You should try to be more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

If two things pass through one another, it simply means they don't interact, or they interact very weakly. In many ways, this is the "natural" state of affairs: we only tend to think no two things can pass through each other because of the strong interactions between what makes up our everyday world. People, walls and chairs are made of stuff that interacts strongly with itself, so that if we walk into a chair, we'll feel a reaction force that stops us going through it. It leads us to false extrapolations grounded on the nongeneral and incorrect notion that "everything takes up space": that's simply not true. Neutrinos interact very weakly with the stuff of your body, so that there is an estimated flux of $10^{11}$ of them through each square centimeter presented to the Sun *each second* and most of them go straight through you.

The question of what stops us zooming in at arbitrarily high magnification is that light is a linear wave, which means that it can encode spatial frequencies of less than or equal to the reciprocal wavelength. Once two features imaged by a telescope become less than one wavelength apart on the CCD array (or retina, or whatever records the image), the incoming light cannot encode any finer detail than this.